# mongoose query doesn't timeout when authentication error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a way to have a query timing out when there is an authentication error.

```
Model.findOne().setOptions({ maxTimeMS : 10 }).exec(function (err, item) {
});
```

I've tried to make use of `maxTimeMS`, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication will fail when mongoose tries to connect to the MongoDB server, which happens before the query above.

Have a look at the link below

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: agree, the authentication error can be detected in the callback of mongoose.connect. However, the authentication will also fail when the query is issued. In this case the query is queued. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the query timing out, rather than have it queued indefinitely